# mysqli last insert id

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, lastinsertid

I would like to associate the image with firstname, lastname...how can I retrieve the last rowand use it to insert to the other table? I tried `$image = $mysqli->insert_id;` then binding but it doesn't work. Can someone help me out?

```
 $image = $mysqli->insert_id;//this should come from table2
 $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("
  insert into table1 (username, firstname, lastname, image) 
  select ?,?,?,image from table2 t2 where username = ? and  t2.id = ? 
   ");
 $stmt->bind_param('sssss', $username, $fname, $lname, $username, $image);
 $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: you need to use `insert_id;` after you executed query with insert, like: `if ($stmt->execute()) $image = $stmt->insert_id;`

Comment: @IlyaBursov so then how do bind `t2.id = ?`

Comment: You need to express your wishes more clear and distinct way

Comment: @user2926655 do you want to insert into table1 or table2?

Comment: You have to get rid of this monster query and explain with plain language what you want to insert, why and where

Comment: @YourCommonSense after I get the last row from table2 I would like to insert it to table1. That is all I need

Comment: ok, so you need to change your query to `insert into table1 (username, firstname, lastname, image) 
  select ?,?,?,image from table2 t2 where username = ? order by t2.id desc limit1`

Comment: @IlyaBursov thanks it works. bzw can I be assured that I always get the last row?

Comment: Just read my answer. this query of yours doesn't guarantee that.

Comment: @user2926655 `order by t2.id desc limit 1` sorts in desc order, which means that only last id in table will be selected

Comment: What **exactly** do you mean by "doesn't work"? What **exactly** is not working in the given snippet?

Comment: @NicoHaase you would scarcely get an answer as the OP left this site 7 years ago

Answer (score 19):

First of All you need to create auto_increment field in you ID

Then You can used 
`$last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);`

Answer (score 1):

> after I get the last row from table2 I would like to insert it to table1. That is all I need

Go on:

1. insert into table 1 with simple regular insert query
2. get last insert id
3. insert into table 2 with simple regular insert query

As simple as that

Comment: Your answer would be conceptually correct if you had not reversed your table names.