# How to get last id inserted to mysql using OOP PHP?

Tags: php

I have the following PHP class, im using this to connect to db and make a new instance:

```
class db{

    public $db_connection;

    public function __construct(){

        $this->db_connection = new mysqli("127.0.0.1","user","passwd","table");
        $this->db_connection->set_charset("utf8");

        if($this->db_connection->connect_errno) {
            echo "Failed to connect to database: " . $db_connection->connect_error;
        }
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        return $this->db_connection->close();
    }
}
```

The code im using to add stuff to the database:

```
$db = new db();

$success = $db->db_connection->query(
    "INSERT INTO users(
        name
    )
    VALUES(
        '".$_POST["firstname"].'
    )"
);
```

Get the ID of the inserted element aboue:

```
if($success){
    $user_id = $db->db_connection->insert_id;
    echo $user_id; // outputs 0
}
```

I am getting the value 0 even tho i have several entries in the database, is there another way around this? The id also have AUTO INCREMENT on the table

Note: Code is simplefied, and not the whole structure, but enough to explain the real issiue.

Comment: There is an issue with quotation marks in your code, does that also exist in your real code? Because this does not look like it will work.

Comment: just as a note: using $POST like that directly in your query is a one-way trip to SQL injection hacking.

Comment: code is tested and works, and YES, this is not the whole code put a simplefied example, just to point out the issiue itself.

Comment: are we to assume you have an auto-incrementing id field on the users table?

Comment: Your quotes are off. You're also using a raw `$_POST`, which is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). Lastly, you should always echo out the MySQL errors

Comment: autocincrement is enabled on the id

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: If you are getting 0 then basically the INSERT has failed and you are not checking correctly that it has failed or succeeded

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli last insert id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738283/mysqli-last-insert-id)

Comment: Enteries are added with success. like mentioned no errors in the code itself

Comment: however the user_id is autoincrement try to insert on it a null value as this : "INSERT INTO users VALUES(NULL,
        ' " . $_POST[firstname]. ' "
    )"

Comment: @RmidiAyoub Not necessary to use a NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you separating the INSERT from polling the insert id? In both cases a failure means you haven't added a row. If you do anything else with the database link in between you'll run into complications which may be what is happening here.

```
if ($db->db_connection->query($insert)) {
   $user_id=$db->db_connection->insert_id;
} else {
   // add some error handling/logging
}
```

Comment: Dont see the difference, $insert is the sql?