# Pulling ID from Table as soon as its assigned

Tags: php, mysql

I have some PHP code which inserts data into a table collected from an html form, it assigns a unique ID automatically when the query is submitted successfully.

Currently I generate a reference, but this is a poor solution as it will end up having duplicate entries long term... How can I pull the unique ID and post it into the echo statement, will I have to run another query to get it? or can it be done in this one block of code?

```
    if($fnameErr === null) {
                    $ref = rand(1, 1000);
                        $query = "INSERT INTO Taxi(fname, lname, contact, unit, snumber, sname, suburb, dsuburb, dt, ref, status) VALUES('{$fname}','{$lname}','{$contact}','{$unit}','{$snumber}','{$sname}','{$suburb}','{$dsuburb}','{$dt}','{$ref}','{$status}')";
                        if (mysqli_query($conn, $query)) {

                        $date = date_create($dt);
                        echo "Thank you! Your booking reference number is {$ref} you will be picked up in front of your provided address at " . date_format($date, 'g:ia \o\n l jS F Y') . ".";

                        }else{
                            echo "<br>Failed<br>";
                            echo mysqli_error($conn);
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "<br>Unable to add your booking.<br>";
                    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [mysqli last insert id](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738283/mysqli-last-insert-id)

Comment: why don't you just auto increment and make it unique in table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the taxi table, you need to create a unique id as the primary key of this table:

```
ALTER TABLE `taxi` ADD `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT FIRST, ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);
```

When you insert some entries, you don't need to make a new id by yourself, but it will be done automatically.

So after the insert query, you can get the new id by:

```
mysqli_query($conn,"INSERT INTO Taxi (fname, lname...) VALUES (...");

echo "New record has id: " . mysqli_insert_id($conn);
```

And you have the id of the last entry.