# getting last auto generated id using mysql_insert_id() in php

Tags: php

I am trying to get last auto incremented customer ID from customer table using mysql_insert_ID function and store it in a variable named lastid and try to send lastid variable using session on another page  and printing it there it won't give any output or error

Comment: FYI, [you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which one is best for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
//---page1.php
// Start a session to be able to store SESSION variables.
session_start();

// Your connection to Database
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");

// Your insert query
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO customers .....";

// Query the database
$conn->query( $insert_query );

// STORE Last_inserted_id into $lastid and $_SESSION
$_SESSION['lastid'] = $lastid = $conn->insert_id;


//---page2.php
// Start a session to be able to use SESSION variables in the new page.
session_start();

// Get value from $_SESSION
echo $_SESSION['lastid'];
```

Taken from documentation [$insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) and [session_start()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php)

Answer (score -2):

`PDO` is the one way to do this if you want to do with `PDO` then here you can follow this:

After a successful query simply use `lastInsertId` method with your `PDO` instance :

```
$lastId = $pdo->lastInsertId(); //This variable will store last insert ID
```

For More details about `lastInsertId()` Method you may check this official Documentation [PHP Last Insert Id](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)

**If you think that will be better to use `mysqli` for you Then**

Just simply after a successful query do like this:

```
$lastId = $mysqli->insert_id; // this is how you will get last inserted id
```

You may follow this stackoverflow question: [Follow This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738283/mysqli-last-insert-id)

Comment: He asked for mysql not PDO

Comment: YES But Moderator already mentioned this to USE PDO instead. Because it's safe.

Comment: PDO,or SQLI. Mysqli used correctly is just as safe as PDO

Comment: Why did you give me negative marks ? @clearshot66 That doesn't make sense. please withdraw that

Comment: You've given two answers here, and neight of them are using the API that the question is asking about

Comment: Yes I just gave him option to use if he want then he can use it.

Answer (score -2):

Since you're familiar with mysql, use mysqli... in that case:

```
$sql = "SELECT max(id) as max FROM table";
```

From there:

```
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
$maxID = $row['max']
```

If you wish to stay in mysql_

```
$sql = "SELECT max(id) as max FROM table";
```

From there:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$maxID = $row['max']
```

Comment: This isn't the way to do this mysqli have built-in property `$mysqli->insert_id`

Comment: It's one method of it, so yes, it is a way to do it. You also have to use insert_id right after an insert. He doesn't state that's what's happening. Max(id) is surefire to get the highest ID (the latest in an auto increment situation) versus insert_id. You should do some research before answering people's questions and giving false advise.

Comment: This can Mis-match sometime and not appropriate.

Comment: The efficient way is to do use of `insert_id` don't just try to re invent the wheel

Comment: _Coding for our nations higher-education facilities._ Frightening! On a busy database this would most likely get a completely different id and really foul things up

Comment: Someone's full of themselves quoting bio's.