# Mysql Prepared Statement Fails - sql query with more than one statement

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, prepared-statement

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO answer (trueOrFalse, answer)
    VALUES(?, ?);
   SET @idanswer01 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  INSERT INTO answer (trueOrFalse, answer)
    VALUES(?, ?);
   SET @idanswer02 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  INSERT INTO answer (trueOrFalse, answer)
    VALUES(?, ?);
   SET @idanswer03 = LAST_INSERT_ID();
  INSERT INTO questions (topic, question, answer1Id, answer2Id, answer3Id)
    VALUES(?, ?, @idanswer01, @idanswer02, @idanswer03);";

$stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn)

mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)
```

The mysqli_stmt_prepare is failing, I think it's because my sql query includes many statements.
Is there a way to execute it or to rewrite the sql query to only be one statement?

[Picture of my two Tables answer and questions][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ZRpx.png

Comment: Just in case you need more information about splitting it into separate queries - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19738283/mysqli-last-insert-id allows you to get the last insert  id, but you can also prepare the answer query once and run it 3 times.

Comment: Can I also suggest that you change the database design slightly.  Insert the question first and then have the question ID as a foreign key on the answer.  This way you can have as many answers to a question you need, currently you have a fixed 3 answers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what exactly do I need to do? Splitting the query into 4 querys and 4 prepared statements and executing them one by one?

Comment: Prepare once, execute multiple times (bind and execute in a loop).

Comment: The duplicate (plus the question I added in the comment) should be enough to get you going.  But I would suggest you look at your database design as well.